# Problems calling my class in python

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I don't know how to keep this simple... I'd like someone too look at my code and tell me why a function of mine is not working like it should...

I have a class:

```
 class PriorityQueue(object):
'''A class that contains several methods dealing with queues.'''

    def __init__(self):
        '''The default constructor for the PriorityQueue class, an empty list.'''
        self.q = []

    def insert(self, number):
        '''Inserts a number into the queue, and then sorts the queue to ensure that the number is in the proper position in the queue.'''
        self.q.append(number)
        self.q.sort()

    def minimum(self):
        '''Returns the minimum number currently in the queue.'''
        return min(self.q)

    def removeMin(self):
        '''Removes and returns the minimum number from the queue.'''
        return self.q.pop(0)

    def __len__(self):
        '''Returns the size of the queue.'''
        return self.q.__len__()

    def __str__(self):
        '''Returns a string representing the queue.'''
        return "{}".format(self.q)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        '''Takes an index as a parameter and returns the value at the given index.'''
        return self.q[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.q.__iter__()
```

And I have this function which will take a text file, and run it through some methods in my class:

```
def testQueue(fname):
    infile = open(fname, 'r')
    info = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    info = info.lower()
    lstinfo = info.split()
    queue = PriorityQueue()
    for item in range(len(lstinfo)):
        if lstinfo[item] == "i":
            queue.insert(eval(lstinfo[item + 1]))
        if lstinfo[item] == "s":
            print(queue)
        if lstinfo[item] == "m":
            queue.minimum()
        if lstinfo[item] == "r":
            queue.removeMin()
        if lstinfo[item] == "l":
            len(queue)
        #if lstinfo[item] == "g":
```

What is not working for me is my calls to `queue.minimum` and `queue.removeMin()`.

I'm completely baffled because if I do it manually in the shell, it all works, when I am reading the file and taking the instructions from the letters in my file, it also works, but `minimum` and `removeMin()` will not display the values in the shell, `removeMin()` however WILL remove the lowest number from the list.

What am I doing wrong that it's not displaying what it is doing, like the class methods define?

IE:

```
 def minimum(self):
     return min(self.q)
```

Shouldn't it display the minimum when I call it from my function?

Comment: please indent your code properly and use the {} button to format it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `def minimum(self): return min(self.q)` won't display anything when called. It'll only display something if you print the output, as in `print(queue.minimum())`. The exception to this is when executing code from the Python prompt/REPL, which prints expressions by default (unless they're `None`).

Comment: So I would need to insert print statements for every one of my if statements to get the correct output?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Or inside each if statement you could store the return value in a variable, like `ret = queue.minimum()`, and then `print(ret)` after the last `if` statement.

Comment: Ok, great.  I can't click it answered for another 4 minutes, and apparently I don't have enough rep to upvote... But I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's working as it should.  You're just returning a value.

If you want the value to display, you need to do either:

```
print queue.minimum()
```

or

```
rval = queue.minimum()
print rval
```

Printing an uncaptured return value is a utility feature of most interpreters. you'll see the same behavior in a javascript console.